# How to check if a page is indexed for getting a backlink from it?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, links, google-index, backlinks, link-building

I have been creating backlinks for a website for the last 2 months. However, I am unable to see any improvement in rankings.

How can I check before creating a link on any website, whether or not that page is indexed so that the link will count?

Answer (score 2):

You can use tools like [MozBar](https://moz.com/) to check the Domain and Page Authority of the page/domain from where you are getting a link.

If it has a good DA and PA, chances are that they are indexed already.

However, backlinks are not the only factor that affects rankings, pay attention to other metrics as well.

Get quality backlinks from reputable websites that can be relatable to your field of business.

Use tools like [Monitor Backlinks](https://monitorbacklinks.com/) to keep a track of backlinks.

Tools used for bulk backlink creation often lead to spammy and low-quality backlinks which have little to no effect on rankings and in some cases may affect the ranks negatively as well.

Refer: [Neil Patel's Blog](https://neilpatel.com/blog/spammers-and-negative-seo/)